# Как сделать вывод фотографий из директории по убыванию(10.jpg 9.jpg ...)?

Tags: php, сортировка

Добрый вечер господа!

Есть код, который берет фотографии из заданной директории и выводит их. Собственно вопрос, сейчас вывод идет по возрастанию 1.jpg 2.jpg ... 10.jpg, как сделать вывод по убыванию 10.jpg 9.jpg ... и т.д.

```
            <?php
                $image_folder_path = './img/superbox/';
                foreach(glob($image_folder_path . "*.jpg") as $img){
                echo "<div class='superbox-list'><div class='imgprw'><img src='$img'/ data-img='$img'/ alt='' class='superbox-img'></div></div>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Возможно, только я не знаю как его можно применить к данному коду.

Comment: Что вам мешает самостоятельно отсортировать массив, который возвращает `glob()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть вам поможет [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)?

`foreach(array_reverse(glob($image_folder_path . "*.jpg")) as $img)`

Comment: Только нужно учитывать, что `glob()` сортирует по алфавиту, а не по цифровым значениям имён. То есть прямой порядок файлов будет такой: `1.jpg, 10.jpg, 2.jpg, 20.jpg...`. Обратный - соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - [обратная натуральная сортировка](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.rsort.php):

```
...
foreach(rsort(glob($image_folder_path . "*.jpg"), SORT_NATURAL) as $img){
...
```